# C++ Disable C1061 error - blocks nested to deep?

Tags: c++

I'm working with an opensource project(a server) and basically on start it loads a big xml item database, with hundreds of item attributes. It uses a massive amount of else/ifs to check for these attributes, I've taken the liberty of adding about 20 more, and now it seems that I've broken the compiler. I've searched around and none of the answers I've found actually give me a viable option so I'm just wondering if you can disable this, I've tried using #pragma (as they use this on a few other warnings themselves).
I haven't had much experience with this part of C++ so I'm probably doing it wrong.

```
#pragma warning(disable:1061)
```

is what I tried, didn't work gave me and error that its not a valid warning. Is it possible to disable this error?

Thank you.

//Edit - Solution
Just wanted to add how I worked around this. I ended up creating a function that I put all my custom attributes in so I wouldn't pass the 128 level limit.

```
bool isCustomAttribute(std::string strValue, int intValue, xmlNodePtr itemAttributesNode, ItemType& it)
```

and I inserted into the array of else ifs lol, maybe not pretty but it was a quick and easy work around.

Comment: I would guess that this error can't be disabled, seems like some form of static limitation that the compiler can't exceed. As a general rule you can't (and shouldn't) suppress error messages. Warnings can be suppressed but should only be done when you are really sure that the warning is invalid in this context.

Comment: If you really are overloading the compiler, asking it not to tell you about it won't help much. I would consider simplifying the code instead, like cutting out some parts and put those in separate functions.

Comment: Depending on your compiler you may be able to increase the maximum block depth, but I think you should probably instead be asking how to better factor your code.

Comment: You can use MinGW. It doesn't give that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inhibit this error, as it is a fatal compiler error, not a warning. [Its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcda4f64.aspx) says:

> Compiler limit : blocks nested too deeply
>
> Nesting of code blocks exceeds the limit of 128 nesting levels.
>   Simplify nesting.

This is a limit of the compiler, but note that 128 nesting levels is far too much in terms of readability and maintainability. You should refactor that code to reach a saner level of nesting (e.g. four levels or less).

Comment: I just looked up what the actual nesting limit is and got the same result. Wonder how many spaces in width each nesting level is...

Comment: To give you an idea of what I'm dealing with this is the source for the item loader, the xml loader starts on about 366, and from there I'm sure you see where the nesting begins... https://github.com/opentibia/server/blob/master/src/items.cpp#L366

Comment: @Skint, strange, I don't see 128 levels of nesting in that code. Are you sure you're not missing some of the closing braces? Not closing the `else if` scopes properly would be deadly indeed.

Comment: @Skint, I also found [this bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315481), which triggers `C1061` even if the code structure is not nested. It might be affecting you.

Comment: Well I can't post all my code in the comment here but I keep all my code separated between #if/#endif's and it looks like I've added probably a good 50 or so to that, so I'm assuming I've done to much lol. as I counted all the opening/closing braces to make sure they match up. I guess I could just put my code in a separate function... Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you all for your answers, you helped me come up with a solution which I updated my first post with.

Comment: This is one of the issues why you can't compile gcc using cl.

Comment: This error can happen with long else-if blocks, for code that has 1-2 levels of nesting. So the error is misleading.